# CSS animation : move a div with the new position relative to the previous

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations

for better performance, I want replace:

```
$('#foo').animate({ left: '+=42px' }, 500);
```

by a transition (or animation) CSS3.
But how can we do to implement "+=" on left property in CSS?

How move a div with the new left position relative to the previous?

thx.

Comment: Actually, I believe CSS and jQuery animations are exactly the same thing in backend =)

Comment: What would cause the transition/animation? What should happen after it ends?

Comment: @Matrix, what you are asking is not possible because CSS is not a programming language, its a styling markup. as far as i know, `+=` does not exist in css. moreover, as paulie wrote above, you will most likely be required to trigger the animation using javascript anyway, so better stick to `.animate`.

Comment: Yes, i'm think about that. I would do a css class like ```.animation {transition: left += 10px}``` and after apply class to DOM element, but I will use JS. So, now the question is: "add class is faster thant change left style property?"^^

Comment: sorry for late reply, next time please add a `@whatever` when you are replying someone so we get a notification :). about performance, you would want to have a look [Here](http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/)

Comment: @Banana I do a lot of tests, I think change left property (without jquery) is the better, thx.

Comment: well, its up to you really. if your target audience's system is fast enough, it wont make a difference which method you use.

Answer (score 9):

In vanilla-js you can't use `+=`, but you can get the old value instead:

```js
document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function() {
  this.style.left = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this).left) + 42 + 'px';
};
```

```css
#foo {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: 2s left;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Click me multiple times</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the transition for smooth animation. you just put transition settings in the CSS of an element like this,

```
#foo {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out
}
```

Then do your incrementation of left with script like this.

```
$('#foo').css('left', '+=42px');
```

You can refer to [this page](https://jsfiddle.net/zkfocujq/).

Comment: my goal is not use JS (and jQuery more) for animations. I use animate, because I use delay, sry i don't write delay n my exemple, its my fault, I edit ;)